# How do I move my LVM 524GB root partition to a new smaller 500GB SSD - and make a backup prior to the move onto an external HDD?

Tags: partitioning, backup, gparted, lvm, mirrors

(running Ubuntu 17.10)

I am new to LVM. I am very familiar with GUID Partition Tables (GPT) and using GParted from a Boot-Disk.

I read somewhere that the big advantage using LVM is that one can manage filesystem(s) and storage on a "hot" system. Is this true -- no need to boot from a Boot-Disk, even when dealing with the root filesystem?

If one can do this on a hot system, can GParted handle the move, or will I be using the Terminal?

This is a production server with VirtualBox running a Windows instance, so minimizing downtime is critical. Nonetheless, would it be advisable to close the VM during a LVM mirroring/backup?

### LVM mirroring to ext. USB HDD.

Is there an elegant way to mirror a "hot" root file system using LVM functions?

### Shrinking root LVM and Moving to new smaller disk

This has been poorly answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/161296/242995). Suggestion 1) using only LVM functions and 2) using GParted and LVM functions.

It's unfortunate the two answers are ambiguous, because with neither is it clear if one would be "hot" -- in a system up state versus booted from an Ubuntu live system (CD or USB) state.

(Note: I would have asked my question in that thread, but somehow I do not have the needed 50 points to do that.)

I just found this very [helpful page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-lvm-concepts-terminology-and-operations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning more about LVM2, I see that the above was a nontrivial question. Shrinking a root LV needs to be done from a live-cd, and anything else can be done on a running system.

But the best discovery I made is that between these two programs, one can do all the work inside a graphical user interface.

to install KDE use

```
sudo apt-get install kvpm
```

to install Partition Manager use

```
sudo apt-get install partitionmanager
```

And for doing an LV backup onto a different hard drive use the mirror option LVM offers.