# How can Partition directory changes every reboot?

Tags: directory, thunderbird, partitioning

The problem is visible on my thunderbird profile folder which I have on the 3rd partition that 14.04 shares with win7.

Direction 1: `/media/XX/64XXXF<u>**1**</u>/Thunderbird/Profiles/67eayrv0.default`
Direction 2: `/media/XX/64XXXF/Thunderbird/Profiles/67eayrv0.default`

Edit: change is after `64XXXF`  1 appears and disappears each reboot

which makes me to change `profiles.ini` each time I open my computer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what the question is here....

Comment: 1 is bold, but of course it's not so visible, I added a comment.

Comment: From the name of the mount-point, it seems that the drive is mounted by `udisks` (when the graphical environment starts). If this drive is present every time and used heavily, I would suggest to add it to `/etc/fstab` and give it a fixed mount point. See http://askubuntu.com/a/125277/16395 (without formatting, that is...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your drive is mounted to a folder named like the partition name or if there is none like the partition ID. The second option might change. You can give the partition a name:

Go into the Disk Utility → select the drive → select the partition the right side → click the wheels below → edit file system → enter a name.

Next time you connect it, the partition should get a fixed name.

Comment: Before I'll try it - it won't format my data, right..? :>

Comment: No panic! It won't.

Comment: It's ubuntu, I don't trust my years of experience on widnows, here magic happens!

I used Gparted and changed labels, now everything looks fine, thank you!