# Folder Permissions for External Hard drives

Tags: permissions, filesystem, external-hdd, kodi

I am trying to set up an Emby server with libraries located on different internal hard drives. Emby requires that I give the user it creates (emby) access to folders/files when I want it to read them. To that end, I have added emby to the group adm and given ownership of the files over to emby.

However, emby still refuses to see my inside my hard drives. It can see files located on my desktop (also owned by emby) but nothing in any external hard drive.

Is there some unique property external hard drive permissions have that I am overlooking?

Comment: Are the external drives NTFS formatted?

Comment: @MichaelBay: When I do "sudo fdisk -l" I get that the hard drive that the OS is on is Type Linux, and both of the external hard drives are of type "Linux filesystem".

Comment: If EXT3/4 then you may need to `chown`.

Comment: @MichaelBay: Can you explain a little bit more? What do I chown?

Comment: The entire partition, I guess. I don't know Emby and I don't know the requirements but perhaps you also need to mount it differently, using the fstab (or just open Disks, select partition, click the cog wheels menu and turn off, as counter-intuitive it may seem, then tick mount at the boot, and Disk will automatically add it to your fstab). https://emby.media/community/index.php?/topic/23174-emby-cant-access-second-hard-drive/

Comment: https://github.com/MediaBrowser/Wiki/wiki/Library-Setup

Comment: Maybe not the whole partition but maybe you need to give emby at least ownership/permissions to all the paths and folders you want to access.

Comment: @MichaelBay was correct when he sent me to the emby.media/community link. In case the link gets removed someday, the solution to this problem is to add the hard drives onto your computer. By default ubuntu sees extra hard drives as removable media. You have create directories and then use fstab to mount the hard drives to those directories. A more complete solution can be found by googling how to add extra hard drives in ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out as much, that it must have been something along those lines. So, is it now set up as you intended? Please consider answering your own question for future references. There aren't many question about this or related specifically to Emby.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change owner and group of the folder/HDD using next command.

```
sudo chown user:user -R /path/to/hdd/folder/
```

Replace the: **`user:user`** with your own user and group that you need it.

The option **`-R`** it will change owner/group across files, folder and sub-folders

Replace the: **`/path/to/hdd/folder/`** with path that you want to change owner/group (Permissions)

Answer (score 0):

As user MichaelBay explains in the discussion of this question, the solution is to mount hard drives to your computer using fstab. A great explanation on how to do that is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125257/how-do-i-add-an-additional-hard-drive). The most upvoted answer explains in great detail on how to do it. The only additional thing I would like to point out is if you have a hard time figuring out the location of your external hard drive's path (the 'dev/sdb..') it is located on the top right corner of gparted.