# Newly mounted disk space not recognised by DUA

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 inside VMWare Fusion application on Mac OS X.

In VMWare Fusion app, Hard Disk space is set to 30 GB and when I run `fdisk -l` command, I can see 30 GB being recognized for Ubuntu.

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x428e85f3

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 39845887 39843840   19G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       39847934 41940991  2093058 1022M  5 Extended
/dev/sda3       41940992 62914559 20973568   10G 83 Linux
/dev/sda5       39847936 41940991  2093056 1022M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Below is the output from gparted application,

[image]

Below is the output from Disk Usage Analyzer application,

[image]

**I would like to understand why newly added 10 GB is not part of DUA.
Is the newly added 10 GB not considered for system usage?**

I followed below post for adding disk space,

[How do I add an additional hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125257/how-do-i-add-an-additional-hard-drive)

Only thing I tried different was mount procedure.

The content of the file /etc/fstab is as below:

```
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=c68dd12e-7f25-4a1d-be68-a136a19ea87d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=fba4ca03-2aa4-42f6-b5ff-da669ea3579b none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
/dev/sda3    /    ext4    defaults    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems that you have added the added space as a new partition, sda3.
2. In /etc/fstab you are trying to mount sda3 as /, but you have already mounted sda1 on / earlier in fstab.

From your question it is not clear to me how you wanted to use your new disk space. But either you will have to mount sda3 on a valid mountpoint (an empty directory) or expand your existing / (root) file system. In the case you will have to:

- Boot your system on a live media.
- Start gparted
- Delete sda3
- Move the swap partition to the right into the free space
- Expand sda1 to the right