# Second HDD not recognized

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I had this issue which was previously fixed by editing the `etc/fstab` file and adding the entry `UUID=DRIVE_UUID MOUNT_POINT FILESYSTEM ARGUMENTS 0 1`. I did a clean install of OS and now the problem persists again. I have enabled Mount at startup from `Disks`.

Basically, the hard drive is inaccessible to use for downloading anything, until I go to `Files` and specifically click on the second hard drive there.

Comment: here you go buddy, this is how i did it https://askubuntu.com/questions/125257/how-do-i-add-an-additional-hard-drive

Comment: I have been trying multiple methods but still cant seem to be able to get it right.

Comment: Why didn't you add it to your `/etc/fstab` (file system table) as you did last time?   *I don't use `gnome-disks` so don't know how it achieves it's mount*