# Ubuntu 18.04 not working after dual boot windows install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive

**Brief Summary**

- I had a fully working Ubuntu system running on a 120GB SSD, with a 1TB HDD as storage. **HDD mounted automatically at /storage**
- Wanted to dual boot windows 10 on my HDD, but alot of difficulty with "partition not found" message. Resizing partitions and formatting and converting to mbr also didn't help
- Wiped clean my HDD, convert to mbr again, and format NTFS, used diskpart etc, still wasn't working.
- Only managed to install after shifting windows installation files to a partition (some known issue with installing from thumbdrives) **Repartitioned HDD to 200gb for windows, and 750gb still for storage**
- Windows works fine, but now **Ubuntu is broken**. After the LUKS password page, it stays for a really long time and then goes into emergency boot.
- My suspicions are because the HDD that was mounted at /storage got wiped and assigned a new disk letter or something, so its trying to load a drive that isnt there (got renamed) and crashes?

Attached some relevant screenshots below. Would really really appreciate all help!! Thank you :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! TLDR: my suspicions were right.

I remembered how i first set up the automount ([How do I add an additional hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125257/how-do-i-add-an-additional-hard-drive)) and remembered editing the `fstab` file.

To fix this, in emergency mode, type `blkid` to find out the new UUID of your harddisk. Then type `sudo vim /etc/fstab` and change the old UUID to the new one and it should work magic again.