# Transmission doesn't have write permissions and throws an error when downloading torrents

Tags: transmission

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS ------------Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-58-generic -------------Architecture: x86-64 –

I have a laptop running Ubuntu acting as a media server. I have transmission installed, I connect to the daemon from my windows computer with the transmission client (not web client, the software client), I add a magnet from the web then I get the error "Error:Permission Denied" after it downloads a small amount. Now obviously this is a permission error where transmission doesn't have the permission to write to the directory. It's frustrating because all the searches I do are saying the same thing and I feel like I've tried it all. It's even more frustrating because I had this working on a previous install of Ubuntu after having this issue at first but now I can't get it working again.

My computer name is raptor. Ubuntu is installed on a 250gb SSD and I want to store my media on a second 1 TB HD I've called raptor1TB. On raptor1TB exists only a directory Media and inside Movies. I have a group named torrent with members raptor and debian-transmission and the folder /media/raptor/raptor1TB/Media has the owner raptor and group torrent with wrx permissions but I still get Error:Permission Denied (/media/raptor/raptor1TB/Media/Movies/*folder being created*

```
raptor@raptor:~$ getent group torrent
torrent:x:1003:debian-transmission,raptor

raptor@raptor:~$ sudo getfacl /media/raptor/raptor1TB/Media/Movies
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/raptor/raptor1TB/Media/Movies
# owner: raptor
# group: torrent
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
```

I believe that when you install transmission a user called debian-transmission is created so that's why I've created group torrent and added that user to it. Some other feedback I've got on reddit suggests the issue may be that my drive isn't mounted correctly since it's not appearing in fstab and Ubuntu does weird things when it auto mounts to /media/. I'll give that a try.

I don't understand what's wrong. I've clicked on every post on google and can't get it working again.

--------------------------SOLVED

My problem ended up being that my second drive wasn't mounted correctly. I used this guide [How do I add an additional hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125257/how-do-i-add-an-additional-hard-drive) , updated the group permissions for the new location and was able to get it working! One small difference, instead of /dev/sda1 I used the UUID found when opening the drive app through Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm new to linux. I did it this way https://vroomtech.io/install-transmission-on-ubuntu-server/

Comment: Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS        
------------Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-58-generic
-------------Architecture: x86-64

Comment: Is Transmission running from the `raptor` account or a different one?

Comment: I believe when it installs it creates a user called debian-transmission and runs from that account. That's why I created group torrent and added the user debian-transmission to it. I would have thought that then giving that group read/write access to the folder would let it work. I asked for help on this on reddit too and one user thinks it might be because my 1 TB drive isn't mounted/listed in fstab and ubuntu breaks stuff that it auto mounts in /media/ so I'm going to to try getting the drive mounted that way and see if it works.

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]