# How to set up Ubuntu with 2 hard drives

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, mount, hard-drive

I have already seen some answers about this but I'd like to get clarification on my particular use case. I have a 1 TB SSD and a 2 TB HDD. I train deep learning models so the SSD is key as I need the fast I/O. On my previous computer I had one hard drive and I went with the paradigm of putting everything I work with under `/home/user`. So I think I want to set things up such that:

- Everything sits on my 1 TB SSD as usual. For this I've created a boot partition (512 MB), and then a normal partition mounted to `/` for the rest of the disk space.
- Then I'll use my 2 TB HDD as a place to store things I don't frequently use. Maybe I'll put my deep learning data there, and pull it onto my SSD when I need to train a model.

The guides I've come across are mostly telling me to mount SSD to `/` (as I've done) and the HDD to `/home` but I don't want to do the latter, as then I wouldn't get that fast I/O for when I'm accessing data. So I've left the SSD mounted to `/`, and now I just don't know what to do to make sure the HDD is accessible. What do I mount it to?

PS: I am literally on the Ubuntu installation screen now.

---

And another quick question. I'll also be cheeky and play some computer games on the side using Wine. I saw on a guide that these should be installed in the HDD. Is that right?

Comment: I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125257/how-do-i-add-an-additional-hard-drive). Should I just ignore the second drive during installation then set it up later?

Comment: @user535733 thanks! I ended up going out on a limb and just typing /hdd in the "mount to" option. I didn't realise I could just type.

Comment: I keep /home inside / (root) on SSD and without data it is tiny. I then mount a data partition and link folders for all data normally in /home. I recently got larger SSD and moved most of /mnt/data to SSD and now use HDD for backup & photo as separate link. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: See [the "Original Answer" section of this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/do-i-need-intel-smart-response-when-installing-ubuntu/282903#282903) for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from partition format problems, normally you have nothing to do: just plug in the disk, use it with Nautilus, check the mount points in Disks for use in Terminal.  Maybe you found old posts with more complicated procedures.  If the disk does not mount automatically, the odds are it has a serious problem.

Comment: You're right. I was way overcomplicating things