# How to set permissions on a permanently mounted disk

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, hard-drive

I've followed instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/125277/1144712) to set up a hdd partition for a new hard drive. How should I set the permissions on that folder such that when I work in it I don't have to use sudo?

I know that I could check answer to the general question "How do I change the permissions on some directory?" But I want to make sure I'm doing things right based on the context.

Comment: You need to use `chown` to do this see the man page [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown)

Comment: Okay, so basically, just the normal `chown` thing. Nothing special about it because it's a mounted disk

Comment: Nope, not specifically. I used the command on an internal disk mounted via fstab in my 20.04 system I used `sudo chown [name]:[name] /media/[mount_point]/storage`. If my name was fred for example, that  would translate to `sudo chown fred:fred /media/fred/storage` Then that took ownership of the drive for user fred. storage is the name of the drive.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: @waltinator I think the other commenter achieved a much more productive use of their time with less typing