# Need help completing the set-up of a new SDD on Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I am new to Ubuntu and need help in completing the install of an additional SDD.

I have physically installed a 2TB m2 SSD. It is showing as mounted in DISKS but not showing up in DISK USAGE ANALYZER.

What am I missing in order to get the extra 2TB added to give my machine more storage?

[DISKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAJpm.png)
[DISK USAGE ANALYER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38eTn.png)

Comment: were all the steps covered and does this answer your question? [How do I add an additional hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125257/how-do-i-add-an-additional-hard-drive)

Comment: I would only use gpt partitioning. You may or may not want one large partition. I typically do not fully partition a new drive until I know what else I may want. More info on data partition(s). https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Answer (score 0):

Your disk is mounted to `/mnt/nvme0n1p1` and can be used for storage.

When a storage device is mounted to anywhere but `/media` subdirectories, it is not treated as a separate disk.

You can always mount the disk somewhere else.

But in current state it is fully available for usage.

Comment: Would best practice to be to mount to /media instead? I was confused as the disk was showing only 250G available in total.

Comment: It doesn't make much difference where to mount a device. I wouldn't recommend to mount it to `/mnt`, because it may be used for temporary mounts. But it is up to you. Maybe create a directory `/media/SSD` and mount it there.

Comment: Will this then have the machines show the total available in the disk usage analyzer? The 2.25T total.

Comment: You can see available space in either case. I don't use the analyzer. But it should show it.